# Materialize: Change floating action button design / image

Tags: html, web, progressive-web-apps, materialize

I'm trying to add a Whatsapp icon to the floating action button to my webpage, but I'm only able to use the icons of materialize, is there any way to change the image/design of the button for a custom round png image?

Thanks in advance!

Pablo

Comment: This seems like a job for the https://gitter.im/Dogfalo/materialize channel. But while you're here, you need to replace `<i class="large material-icons">mode_edit</i>` with your own image.

Comment: Hi @SeanDoherty thanks for quick tip! By replacing this I'm getting a plain colored circle with non icon or image. I've tried to change it to transparent but I can only the the shadow... I will try in parallel in gitter.im/Dogfalo/materialize, any other idea will be more than welcome!

Comment: I will put a pen together tomorrow 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple. Replace the `i` tag with an img:

```
<a class="btn-floating btn-large red">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/56" alt="Button Image">
</a>
```

This will cover the entire FAB - I'm using a placeholder the exact same dimenions of the button (56px by 56px). If you want to reduce the image to the size of the default icon, have it circular ect, it's:

```
a.btn-floating img {
  padding: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width:100%;
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/NWNOVby).

Comment: Thanks a lot @SeanDoherty! I was able to solve the issue, seems that the reference I was pointing to in the img src was giving me issues, so when using a url worked well I realized the issue comes from there. Also extremely helpful the CSS since I was able to customize some stuff